# ==284==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-underflow

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, circular-buffer, boyer-moore, stackunderflow

I am writing a more simple version of the Boyer Moore algorithm, and I need to use circular buffer because there could be a really big input. The program should write all positions of symbols which have been compared with a pattern. But my program failed tests when I committed it to a gitlab server. These testes check undefined behaviour in the program, so the reason of their failure is quite obvious. However, I can't spot UB. The only hint is an error message but I don't understand how to use these byte addresses to solve my problem. Also, How "pat" can be underflowed if it is just a basic string?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_PATTERN_LEN 16
#define BUF_SIZE 16
#define ALPH_SIZE 256

void calculate_shifts(const unsigned char *str, int len_str, int *shifts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPH_SIZE; i++) 
        shifts[i] = len_str;
    for (int i = 0; i < len_str - 1; i++) 
        shifts[str[i]] = len_str - 1 - i;
}

int read_str(int max_len, unsigned char *str_place, int *is_patread, int *ind_EOF) {
    int count_read = 0;
    int ch = EOF;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_len; i++) {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == EOF) {
            if (!(*ind_EOF)) 
                *ind_EOF = 1; 
            break;

        }
        if ((ch == '\n') && (*is_patread == 0)) {
            *is_patread = 1;
            break;
        }
        str_place[i] = (char) ch;
        count_read++;
    }
    return count_read;
}

typedef struct {
    unsigned char *buf;
    int idxIn;
    int idxOut;
    int size;
} Ring_buf;

void Ring_put(Ring_buf *ring, unsigned char symbol) {
    ring->buf[ring->idxIn++] = symbol;
    if (ring->idxIn >= ring->size) 
        ring->idxIn = 0;
}

void Ring_push_idxOut(Ring_buf *ring, int jump) {
    int new_indxOut = ring->idxOut + jump;
    if (new_indxOut >= ring->size) new_indxOut -= ring->size;
    ring->idxOut = new_indxOut;
}

void Ring_init(Ring_buf *ring, unsigned char *buf, int size) {
    ring->size = size;
    ring->buf = buf;
    ring->idxIn = 0;
    ring->idxOut = 0;
}

unsigned char Ring_showch(const Ring_buf *ring, int idx) {
    int actual_idx = ring->idxOut + idx;
    if (actual_idx >= ring->size) 
        actual_idx -= ring->size;
    return ring->buf[actual_idx];
}

int Ring_put_nchars(Ring_buf *ring, int num, int ind_EOF) {
    if (ind_EOF) return 0;
    int count_read = 0;
    int ch = EOF;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        Ring_put(ring, ch);
        count_read++;
    }
    return (count_read == num);
}

void search_substr(Ring_buf *ring, const unsigned char *pat, int pat_len, int ind_EOF) {
    int shift = 0, local_shift = 0, shift_addition = 0, shifts[ALPH_SIZE];
    calculate_shifts(pat, pat_len, shifts);
    for (;;) {
        while (local_shift <= (ring->size - pat_len)) {
            int j = pat_len - 1;
            for (; (Ring_showch(ring, local_shift + j) == pat[j]) && (j >= 0) ; j--) 
                printf("%d ", shift + local_shift + j + 1);
            if (j < 0) {
                shift_addition = shifts[pat[pat_len - 1]];
                local_shift += shift_addition;
            } else {
                printf("%d ", shift + local_shift + j + 1);
                shift_addition = shifts[Ring_showch(ring, local_shift + j)];
                if (j == 0) 
                    shift_addition = pat_len;
                if ((shift_addition == pat_len) && (j < pat_len - 1) && (pat[pat_len - 1] == pat[0])) 
                    shift_addition--;
                local_shift += shift_addition;
            }
        }
        int req_addplace = pat_len - 1 - (ring->size - 1 - local_shift);
        shift += req_addplace;
        if (!Ring_put_nchars(ring, req_addplace, ind_EOF))
            break;
        Ring_push_idxOut(ring, req_addplace);
        local_shift -= req_addplace;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned char pat[MAX_PATTERN_LEN + 1] = {'\0'};
    unsigned char str[BUF_SIZE] = {'\0'};
    int is_patread = 0, ind_EOF = 0;
    int pat_len = read_str(MAX_PATTERN_LEN + 1, pat, &is_patread, NULL);
    int str_len = read_str(BUF_SIZE, str, &is_patread, &ind_EOF);
    if (!str_len || !pat_len)
        return 0;
    Ring_buf ring;
    Ring_init(&ring, str, str_len);
    search_substr(&ring, pat, pat_len, ind_EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

`input: example\nthis is simple example`

`output: 7, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 20, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16`

```
the error message:
==284==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-underflow on address 0x7ffd3cdb915f at pc 0x00000040166d bp 0x7ffd3cdb8b90 sp 0x7ffd3cdb8b80
READ of size 1 at 0x7ffd3cdb915f thread T0
    #0 0x40166c in search_substr /builds/J6i_AJma/0/c_programming_autumn/23203/i.bogachenkov/template/lab1-0/src/main.c:87
    #1 0x40187b in main /builds/J6i_AJma/0/c_programming_autumn/23203/i.bogachenkov/template/lab1-0/src/main.c:121
    #2 0x7f068531ab96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x400b69 in _start (/builds/J6i_AJma/0/c_programming_autumn/23203/i.bogachenkov/template/build_lab1-0/lab1-0+0x400b69)
Address 0x7ffd3cdb915f is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 31 in frame
    #0 0x4016af in main /builds/J6i_AJma/0/c_programming_autumn/23203/i.bogachenkov/template/lab1-0/src/main.c:111
  This frame has 5 object(s):
    [32, 49) 'pat:112' <== Memory access at offset 31 underflows this variable
    [96, 112) 'str:113'
    [128, 132) 'is_patread:114'
    [144, 148) 'ind_EOF:114'
    [160, 184) 'ring:119'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-underflow /builds/J6i_AJma/0/c_programming_autumn/23203/i.bogachenkov/template/lab1-0/src/main.c:87 in search_substr
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1000279af1d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1000279af1e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1000279af1f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3
  0x1000279af200: f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1000279af210: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x1000279af220: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1[f1]00 00 01 f2
  0x1000279af230: f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 f2 f2 04 f2 04 f2 00 00 00 f3
  0x1000279af240: f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1000279af250: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1000279af260: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1000279af270: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==284==ABORTING
```

Comment: Start by creating a [mcve], by removing portions of code and seeing if you still have the issue.

Comment: `read_str()` doesn't add a null terminator to the string.

Comment: @Barmar, I thought that they were added when it was initialized. I need to read chars to a buffer, so I didn't put a null terminator

Comment: What will happen if the input fills the entire buffer? Perhaps you should subtract 1 from the size when calling `read_str()`.

Comment: @Barmar, could you explain what will happen if the buffer is filled?

Comment: There won't be a null terminator, since you'll overwrite it with the last character of input. I haven't checked the rest of the code to see if it needs it. Maybe not, since you pass explicit lengths around.

Comment: The initialization `{'\0'}` is a fit funky... it means {[0] = '\0'} and the rest are 0 initialized so you might as well just do `{0}`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do all that work in `read_str()` opposed to `fgets()`?

Comment: @AllanWind -- _"The initialization `{'\0'}` is a bit funky...."_ -- I have always preferred `{'\0'}` for string buffers as a way to make them stand out a bit and to make it explicit that the intention is to initialize an empty string, but I don't think that this is overly common among C programmers.

Comment: @adabsurdum With experience you earned the right to your preference (in my book) and you would know that `{'\n'}` means `{'\n', 0, 0, ... }`.  I had to double check that it indeed only sets the first element.  I usually prefer whatever is most concise.

Comment: @AllanWind -- yes, it is admittedly a quirk of mine. When GCC and Clang compilers start supporting the new C23 empty braces initializers I will probably just use that. I don't know why exactly `{0}` has always rubbed me slightly the wrong way for string buffers but `{}` seems fine, except that part of me thinks that if I am going to type anything between the braces it might as well carry some semantic meaning. In general I agree about concision; sometimes I will trade a bit of concision for, let's say, documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `main()` / `read_str()`: `int pat_len = read_str(MAX_PATTERN_LEN, pat, &is_patread, NULL)` is undefined behavior (segfault) when `ind_EOF` is dereferenced.  Either treat it an error or only dereference `ind_EOF` if not `NULL`:

   ```
           if(ind_EOF)
               *ind_EOF = 1;
   ```
2. `read_str()`: Prefer to initialize out parameters instead of relying on caller to do it (before the loop):

   ```
   if(ind_EOF)
      *ind_EOF = 0;
   ```
3. `read_str()`: The out parameter `str_place` should be a string, i.e. `'\0'` terminated, if successful.  The minimal fix is to pass in `max_len` one less than the array size as you already zero initialize the input strings:

   ```
   unsigned char pat[MAX_PATTERN_LEN + 1] = {0};
   unsigned char str[BUF_SIZE + 1] = {0};
   int is_patread = 0, ind_EOF = 0;
   int pat_len = read_str(MAX_PATTERN_LEN, pat, &is_patread, NULL);
   int str_len = read_str(BUF_SIZE, str, &is_patread, &ind_EOF);
   ```
4. `read_str()`: Consider using `fgets()` and eliminate both the `is_patread` and `ind_EOF` arguments as only the 2nd caller uses `ind_EOF`.

   ```
   size_t read_str(size_t n, char *s) {
       return fgets(s, n, stdin) ? strlen(s) : 0;
   }
   ```

   ... and don't read more input from the user if you know you are going to return anyways (`!pat_len`):

   ```
   int main(void) {
       char pat[MAX_PATTERN_LEN];
       size_t pat_len = read_str(MAX_PATTERN_LEN, pat);
       if(!pat_len) return 0;

       char str[BUF_SIZE];
       size_t str_len = read_str(BUF_SIZE, str);
       if(!str_len) return 0;
       int ind_EOF = feof(stdin);
       // ...
   ```
5. `search_substr()`: Check that `j` is in the expected range before using it (i.e. swap the order of the two expressions of the controlling expression):

   ```
           for (; ((j >= 0) && Ring_showch(ring, local_shift + j) == pat[j]); j--)
   ```
6. `Ring_put_nchars()`: With example input the  blocks in  in the call `ch = getchar()`.  I don't know if it's expected behavior but it's strange to read in a function that is meant to write.
7. `read_str()`: `str_place[i] = (char) ch;` it's a little odd that you don't use `(unsigned char)`.

Comment: I understand that `read_str()` is quite weird. At first it was written for the basic BM algorithm, but then I modified it for a ring buffer version (that is the reason why I don't put null terminator in the end of string). So there could be other bugs in that program. The main problem was `5.` (so dumb that I am even ashamed). With your fix program passes all the tests on server. Thank you very much for that :)

Comment: Never apologize.  It slows down your learning.  It's a good day when you learn something and it was my pleasure.